# Use both display: none and display:flex;

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div that when you hover over it, one of it's child elements - another div - is supposed to fade in and out using JQuery. To get a better idea you can have a look at the following [codepen](http://codepen.io/Tiwaz89/pen/PZNKYK).

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/375x250">
    <div class="description">
      <h3>Description</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#container .item {
  width: 375px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

#container .item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#container .item .description {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(function () {

  $('.item').hover(
    function () {
      // mouse over
      $('.description').fadeIn(1000);
    },
    function () {
      // mouse out
      $('.description').fadeOut(1000);
    }
  );

});
```

In the CSS  > `.description` section I use both `display: none` (required by JQuery so that the div is initially hidden) and `display: flex` (used to center the content nicely). But when the two are combined the last `display` property is read and `display: none` is ignored. How do I make this thing work?

Comment: It would've been better in my opinion if you could say something like 'layout: flex;' instead.

Comment: No, the problem is not `display: flex`, the problem is (ab)using `display` to hide things. This was a bad design of the language. Display L3 introduces `box-suppress` to address this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you want to remove the `display: flex` from your CSS since it's the one being used (as it's overwriting the previous `display: none`)

Then in your JS, replace `fadeIn` with the following a combination of `css` and `animate` to make the effect happen.

```
$(function() {
    $('.item').hover(
        function() {
            $('.description').css({opacity: 0, display: 'flex'}).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 1000);
        },
        function() {
            $('.description').fadeOut(1000);
        });
});
```

the `css` function here is used before every effect to set the `opacity: 0` and `display: flex` after which it will `animate` `opacity: 1`

Then on `fadeOut` there's nothing special that should happen since that will just fade to `display: none`

Comment: What I basically ended up doing was remove the 'display:none' and replaced it with 'opacity: 0' in the scss. Then in the JQuery I replaced the fadeIn and fadeOut with  .animate() and changing the opacity to 1 or 0. i.e. $('.description').animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);

Comment: @DeanGibson I was thinking of adding that to the answer to since that makes total sense, good solution!

Answer (score 1):

Your container is the flex container, so shouldn't the flex item inside have an initial `display: none`. The CSS rule will take the last property definition, so a repeated display property will just override the previous definition. I played with your codepen and I have update it. [Is this what you're looking for?](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMNjYa)

```
.description {
    /* ... */
    display: none;
    /* ... */
}   // .description
```